# Run diff on symlinks

Tags: symbolic-link, diff

I have two folders containing a number of broken symlinks.

Is there a way to make `diff` compare the target of the links instead of trying to follow the links?

Comment: I believe there's no option to have it prevent dereferencing the link. First hit on Google shows me the feature request with a proposed patch on the diffutils mailing list: [diff: support for --no-dereference option](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-diffutils/2012-01/msg00001.html)

Answer (score 1):

With 'content of the links' I assume you mean 'target of the link'. If that's correct, then yes, there is. Sort of. And you have to get creatie with shell redirection :)

```
diff -u \
<(cd /path/to/dir1 && find . -type l -exec stat '{}' '+' | grep 'File:' | sort) \
<(cd /path/to/dir2 && find . -type l -exec stat '{}' '+' | grep 'File:' | sort)
```

What this does is run `diff` with as input the output of two commands:

```
cd /path/to/dir1 && find . -type l -exec stat '{}' '+' | grep 'File:' | sort
cd /path/to/dir2 && find . -type l -exec stat '{}' '+' | grep 'File:' | sort
```

These `find | grep | sort` commands display the name and target of all symlinks it can find in dir1 and dir2, together with their targets. So the net result is that you'll see which symlinks are different.

(Edited from the original answer, which included the full path to the filename in the output of `ls`, and therefore showed every file as different. Worked around this by using `cd` first. Also if the symlinks had different dates and times, diff would show them as different too. Worked around that by using `stat` to extract the information that we actually want.)